# Sort a list with duplicates based on another list with same items but different order

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing, duplicates

I have two lists of strings like this (**two lists have the same items but in different orders**):

```
lst1 = ['C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'O', 'O', 'H']
lst2 = ['H', 'H', 'C', 'O', 'H', 'O', 'H', 'C']
```

To sort `lst2` based on `lst1`, I want to find the `lst2` index for each item in `lst1`. For duplicates I want to **take the smallest index that has not been taken**.

I want to know the fastest way to get a index list like this:

```
ids = [2, 0, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6]
```

then I can sort `lst2` by

```
newlst2 = [lst2[i] for i in ids]
```

Since there are duplicates, the normal way of getting list indices

```
ids = [lst2.index(x) for x in lst1]
```

will give the wrong result

```
ids = [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: ```ids = [2, 0, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6]``` is the expected result

Comment: "the normal way of getting list indices `ids = [lst2.index(x) for x in lst1]`" that is *not* the normal way of doing that. That is a very inefficient way. You should generally avoid that.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to compute `newlst2` in this convoluted way? Or at all? Don't you simply get the same as `lst1`, which you have already?

Comment: Because in reality the strings are given by an attribute of a Molecule class. As you might notice, the strings represents chemical elements. I want to sort the atoms of a CH3COOH molecule based on the order of name "CH3COOH".

Comment: I still don't get it. So you don't actually have `lst1 = ['C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'O', 'O', 'H']` but instead have the string "CH3COOH"? And then you expand it to that `lst1`? In which case at that point you do have that list?

Comment: So, let's say I have a CH3COOH molecule, which consists of 8 atoms of course. Each atom has an index. The order of the atom indices can be very disordered, and if we print the chemical symbol of each atom from id 0 to 7, it can be H2COHOHC just like ```lst2```. I want to normalize the indices of my atoms so that the symbol I got from the molecule will always be CH3COOH. Is this clear for you?

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is to identify molecules (chemical names) from groups of atoms. I cannot output something like H2COHOHC which people cannot understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although in theory not the fastest `O(n2)`, for the use case of sorting the position of atoms in molecules, as indicated in the comments (assuming molecules of size of the order of the sample: 10ish atoms), this simple approach, using builtins is probably faster than other more sophisticated answers (`O(n)`) requiring several imports of external libraries.

You can index each element of `lst1` (`start`) into `lst2` (`model`), and replace the element found in `lst2` with `None`:

```
start = ['C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'O', 'O', 'H']
model = ['H', 'H', 'C', 'O', 'H', 'O', 'H', 'C']

res = []
for elt in start:
    idx = model.index(elt)
    res.append(idx)
    model[idx] = None
    
res   # [2, 0, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: The question is for "the fastest way", and this is only O(n^2).

Comment: Is "external libraries" supposed to refer to `collections`, which is a *part* of *one* library, Python's *standard* library?

Answer (score 5):

You could collect each value's indexes and then use those collections. Takes O(n) time.

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

indexes = defaultdict(deque)
for i, x in enumerate(lst2):
    indexes[x].append(i)

ids = [indexes[x].popleft() for x in lst1]
```

Comment: With all your imports, you are 2.5 times slower than my naive `O(n2)` - big O notation is only half the story!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Ok, then here's an even faster solution: `ids = [2, 0, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6]`.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Also, how exactly did you measure it? I tried as well now, with those tiny lists, and mine was only about factor 1.2 slower.

Comment: The question is for "the fastest way", 1.2 times slower, is slower! Can't beat `ids = [2, 0, 1, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6]` though!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Doubling the lists, mine's already factor 1.5 times *faster* than yours, and at length 96 (a bit under the 100 you now mention in your answer), mine's about factor 5.5 faster.